# Capture subdirectory names as variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to write code that will read through a given directory, list the folder names within, and allow me to save them as variables. This will later be used to run searches off those names.

I'm using this right now, which will list out all the folders correctly, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
import os
print [os.path.abspath(name) for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

Comment: You might want to look into **os.walk()**. There are many examples if you search the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save the folder names, then just assign the list you are creating:

```
directories = [os.path.abspath(name) 
               for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

Then later you can iterate through this list and do something with it:

```
for dir_ in directories:
    your_search_function(dir_)
```